# Man in the middle using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, tcp

I wish to test a subsystems which communicates with another subsystems via tcp. I have used the following:

```
"iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport "+port_number" -j DROP"
```

to stop the traffic on a port so that I could via a script send my own data to the system under test. This worked really well.

I now wish however to forward the traffic to my script instead of simply dropping it. I then wish to manipulate the data in my script before forwarding it to the subsystem under test.

Can I do this using iptables? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (incoming traffic to port `1234` will be redirected to `4321` in the localhost, where you could have your script listening):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4321 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4321
```

If you want to access the port `1234` from the same machine as well, you'll need to add an `OUTPUT` rule, as `PREROUTING` isn't used by the loopback interface:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 1234  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4321
```

Now, on the server, you can try listening with `nc -l 4321` (here you could use your own script). On a client, try `nc server_host_name_or_ip 1234` and write anything to verify the server is correctly doing the redirection.

Don't forget to save the `iptables` configuration!